# Lucee throws 500 error on any cfm file in a subdirectory

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I have a legacy app running on Azure, IIS 10, Lucee 5.whatever.  Runs fine.  BUT, in a given subdirectory, trying to execute ANY ColdFusion code produces a 500 error.  Example:

`www.mysite.com`  works fine

`www.mysite.com/whatever/` works fine

`www.mysite.com/whatever/admin/` throws an error, even if the .cfm file only has HTML in it.

I enabled full debug output in the server administrator; it displays fine on the pages that don't throw a 500, but on the ones that do, all I get is the 500.

Permissions are consistent through the directories... i.e. they're the same at the level of the files that work as the ones that don't.

IIS is setup for pass-through authentication.

Not sure what else to check.  Help please? :)

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: You also forgot to mention if you are getting 500 error code from IIS or Tomcat directly. Do you get the same message via Lucee default port 8888?

Comment: Nothing at all in the logs.  Not sure how to call up the app via 8888.

Comment: @RobG - To confirm you checked all recent logs?

Comment: To clarify, *Lucee's* logs are the relevant ones, not IIS logs. But you should also enable IIS request tracing, and check for IIS URL rewrite issues.

Comment: ...and of course detailed IIS errors, so that it says more than "500".

Comment: Yes, I checked the Lucee logs.  Nothing in them at all.

Comment: Log into your win box and call the URLs locally. That way you should see more detailed information about your 500 error instead of a IIS default 500 public error page. Also, you access Lucee through port  8888 (bypassing IIS) by accessing it also locally with www.mysite.com:8888/whatever/admin/ . But you should consider URLRewrite rules rewriting your IIS, so translate it when accessing Lucee directly. Another hint would be to look at your win event viewer for IIS errors.